# Publishing MVC webapp to Azure webapp service giving default page

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, publishing

I have an out of the box MVC C# web-application that is hosted in Azure Devops, when I publish to my app service I am getting this default page:
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHQTP.png)

I have checked the Kudu Console and all my files are in the directory. I also attached a debugger an I can see that it doesn't enter my application at all (global.asax and startup.cs).

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: you said you checked the kudu console and all your files are there, are they in the correct directory ?

Comment: Make sure all your files are under wwwroot directory, if this doesn't solve your issue. Provide the details how you deployed your app to azure app service.

Comment: @D.J. I don't know what you mean by correct directory but mine are in wwwroot.

Comment: @TonyJu Steps are: created app service, downloaded publish profile, pushed solution to devops, from VS clicked on publish, imported profile (downloaded from azure) -> getting default page.

Comment: i meant wwwroot with "correct directory", sorry for being unclear